# IE8 scrollHeight property causing problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll

I have a DIV element where I can add and remove contents from it, and based on my readings, the scrollHeight property is a measure of the DIV's content height. I have a portion of javascript code that sets the DIV to a specific height based on the scrollHeight property:

```
  if (div.scrollHeight <= 25)
  {
    div.style.height = "25px";
  }
  else if (div.scrollHeight > 25)
  {
    div.style.height = "50px";
  }
```

The code works with IE6 and IE7, but when it is run in IE8, once the style height is set to a value of 50px, the scrollHeight property keeps returning a value of 50px even though I removed some of the DIV's content to make it fit a 25px height. So the problem is that the size of the DIV does not contract to the smaller size after its expansion under IE8. May I get help with fixing this up?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the elements are not totally removed from IE's nodelist?
Try to set them as `null` and then reload the content.